# gcc ld: method to determine link order of static libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, static-linking

My executables are linked with many static libraries, typically between 50 and 100 archives on Linux. Occasionally there are dependency cycles in these archives. The order that these libraries appear on the link command line is significant, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc). Attempting to manually order this many libraries is time-consuming at minimum, especially when there are cycles present.

Question: is there a utility or technique that will analyze a code base and produce a correct link command line ordering?

Comment: I see. Usually, One would want to resolve them automatically rather than finding the correct order for yourself. I thought you asked you want to avoid fixing the order manually. May I ask why you want to *know* the order? Is it because you are worried --start-group -- --end-group will be slower ?

Comment: @l3x, It has to do with performance. Predetermining the order allows the linker to scan each library only once. This can make a big difference when you are trying to link 70 libraries for an executable.

Comment: If ttere are dependency cycles there is no correct order. You will either have to isolate the libraries that have these cycles between them and use start/end group around those libraries only, or combine those libraries and `tsort` them.

Comment: @ELP, yes, but cycles can be identified and isolated with `--start-group`/`--end-group` and the remaining libs topo-sorted. It is what is have been doing by trial and error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> You want a **topological sort**.

The `tsort` program will do that, but you'll need to do more work to use it [be prepared to write a perl/python script].  Also, there is another way as well. And, I *will* get to the "howto" below as I've done this sort of thing before.

---

> **The short answer:** Use `--start-group` *liblist* `--end-group` and be done with it.

For a few reasons:

An ld group is *smart*.  It doesn't just loop on the files.  It makes an initial pass through the group, but remembers the symbols.  So, on subsequent passes it uses the cached symbol table information, so it's very fast.

For complex interactions, you may *not* be able to get rid of all the *cycles* with a toposort, so you'll *still* need a group even if *liblist* has been topo sorted.

Just how much time are we talking about?  And, how much time do you think will be saved?  How will you measure things to prove you really need this.

---

> **Go for the gold**

Instead of using `ld`, consider using `ld.gold`.  It has been rewritten from scratch to *not* use libbfd [which is slow] and operates on ELF files directly.  The primary motivation for creating it was simplicity and *speed*.

---

> **How to topologically sort a library list**

If we do `info coreutils`, the tsort section will give an example of how to toposort a symbol table.

But, before we can get to that, we'll need to get the symbols.  For a `.a` file, `nm` can provide the list: `nm -go <liblist>`.

The output will look like:

```
libbfd.a:
libbfd.a:archive.o:0000000000000790 T _bfd_add_bfd_to_archive_cache
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U bfd_alloc
libbfd.a:archive.o:0000000000000c20 T _bfd_append_relative_path
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U bfd_assert
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U bfd_bread
libbfd.a:archive.o:00000000000021b0 T _bfd_bsd44_write_ar_hdr
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U strcpy
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U strlen
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U strncmp
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U strncpy
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U strtol
libbfd.a:archive.o:                 U xstrdup
libbfd.a:bfd.o:                 U __asprintf_chk
libbfd.a:bfd.o:00000000000002b0 T _bfd_abort
libbfd.a:bfd.o:0000000000000e40 T bfd_alt_mach_code
libbfd.a:bfd.o:                 U bfd_arch_bits_per_address
libbfd.a:bfd.o:0000000000000260 T bfd_assert
libbfd.a:bfd.o:0000000000000000 D _bfd_assert_handler
libbfd.a:bfd.o:0000000000000450 T bfd_canonicalize_reloc
libbfd.a:bfd.o:                 U bfd_coff_get_comdat_section
libbfd.a:bfd.o:0000000000000510 T _bfd_default_error_handler
libbfd.a:bfd.o:0000000000000fd0 T bfd_demangle
libbfd.a:bfd.o:                 U memcpy
libbfd.a:bfd.o:                 U strchr
libbfd.a:bfd.o:                 U strlen
libbfd.a:opncls.o:0000000000000a50 T bfd_openr
libbfd.a:opncls.o:0000000000001100 T bfd_openr_iovec
libbfd.a:opncls.o:0000000000000b10 T bfd_openstreamr
libbfd.a:opncls.o:0000000000000bb0 T bfd_openw
libbfd.a:opncls.o:0000000000001240 T bfd_release
libbfd.a:opncls.o:                 U bfd_set_section_contents
libbfd.a:opncls.o:                 U bfd_set_section_size
libbfd.a:opncls.o:0000000000000000 B bfd_use_reserved_id
libbfd.a:opncls.o:00000000000010d0 T bfd_zalloc
libbfd.a:opncls.o:00000000000011d0 T bfd_zalloc2

libglib-2.0.a:
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000100 T g_allocator_free
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:00000000000000f0 T g_allocator_new
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000150 T g_blow_chunks
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000160 T g_list_push_allocator
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000060 T g_mem_chunk_alloc
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000090 T g_mem_chunk_alloc0
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000110 T g_mem_chunk_clean
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000120 T g_mem_chunk_reset
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:00000000000001b0 T g_node_pop_allocator
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:00000000000001a0 T g_node_push_allocator
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:                 U g_return_if_fail_warning
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:                 U g_slice_alloc
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:                 U g_slice_alloc0
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:                 U g_slice_free1
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gallocator.o:0000000000000190 T g_slist_pop_allocator
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:                 U g_private_get
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:                 U g_private_set
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:                 U g_return_if_fail_warning
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:00000000000010d0 T g_slice_alloc
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:0000000000001770 T g_slice_alloc0
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:00000000000017a0 T g_slice_copy
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:00000000000017e0 T g_slice_free1
libglib-2.0.a:libglib_2_0_la-gslice.o:0000000000001ae0 T g_slice_free_chain_with_offset
```

So, the syntax will be:

```
<libname.a>:<objname.o>:<address> [TDB] <symbol>
<libname.a>:<objname.o>:          U     <symbol>
```

and we'll need to extract *libname.a*, symbol *type* (e.g. T, D, B, U), and the *symbol*.

We create a list of files.  In each file struct, we remember all symbols and their types.  Any type that is *not* `U` [undefined symbol] will *define* the symbol.

Note that as we build the symbol table, a library may have multiple U's [in various .o's] that refer to a symbol defined by another .o within it.  So, we only record the symbol once and if we see a non-U type, we "promote" it (e.g. if we saw `U foo` and later saw `T foo` we change the type of *foo* to `T` [likewise for D and B].

Now we traverse the file list (e.g. `curfile`).  For each symbol in the file's symbol table, if it's of type `U` [undefined], we scan *all* files looking for a non-U symbol definition.  If we find one (in `symfile` (e.g.)), we can output a dependency line for tsort: `<curfile> <symfile>`.  We repeat this for all files and symbols.

Note that this is bit wasteful because we could output many *file* dependency lines that are identical because the above will generate a line for each *symbol*.  So, we should keep track of the lines output and only output a dependency line for unique file pairs.  Also, note, it *is* possible to have both `foo bar` *and* `bar foo`.  That is, actually, a *cycle*. While we just want one copy of `foo bar` and/or `bar foo`, they should *not* exclude one another.

Okay, so now feed the output of the above to `tsort` and it will give us the *topologically sorted* version of *liblist* that we want.

As should be obvious, the script parsing can take some time, so the tsort output should be cached in a file, and rebuilt in a makefile, based upon a dependency list of *liblist*

---

> **Convert some .a files to .o files**

If a given library uses all [or most] of the its .o files, instead of doing `ar rv libname.a ...`, consider doing `ld -r libname.o ...`.

This is similar in approach to creating a shared library .so file, but the "big" .o can still be statically linked.

Now, you have a single .o that will link faster than the .a because the intra-library links have already been resolved.  Also, it will help with dependency cycles a bit.

A slight extension to the topo script could tell you which libraries are good candidates for this.

Even if the normal build makefiles can't be changed, the "final" top level could take a .a, either extract it into .o's, or use an ld force load option with -r to get the "big" .o

Comment: Back in the day we used something like `ar tvf libXXX.a \`nm -no *.o|tsort\`` but I forget the details, it's been 25 years or more.

Comment: @EJP Yep. 25 years is about how far back I had to go in memory to dredge up the algorithm :-).  Sigh.  I remember a couple of years back, when I first discovered ld groups, I was "wow, no more topo sorting!" and changed all my build scripts to use them. It's seems, herein, that "what's old is new again ..."

Comment: Really great answer. One question is whether names `nm` generates should be demangled or not. I suppose leaving them mangled would provide a more precise match, but be harder for humans to read, is that correct?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod What humans can or cannot read is irrelevant. The output is piped directly into `tsort`, and from there possibly into `uniq` and then surely something else to remove everything but the filename. Can remember the details but it used to be listed on *man 1 ar*. Humans don't have to read it at all.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod `ld` [and `nm`] only know the mangled names, so it's more proper to use them as is.  Faster [demangling is slow].  And, more portable, because we don't have to divine the mangling scheme for the tool chain that created them and reverse it.  If we guess wrong, we could have a collision.  I'd do demangling if I wanted the topo script to print a progress message, but I'd still use the mangled names when trying for a symbol match.

Comment: How would I use this method when mixing dynamic and static libraries. Example: gcc -static-libgcc -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/glxmodule.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ../../../glx/.libs/libglx.a ../../../glx/.libs/libglxdri.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
-g -O2 -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libglx.so -o .libs/libglx.so \
-Wl,-Bstatic -lglx -lGL -lbsd -lXext -lX11 -lxcb -lXdmcp -lXau \
-Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -ldl -lpthread

Answer (score 3):

The BSD world have a wrapper around `nm` to do the job of producing a `tsort`-appropriate input called [`lorder`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?format=html&query=lorder(1)). It's really just a shell script, and you can see the [source code in FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.bin/lorder/lorder.sh). It does exactly what the existing answer says, but in the form of two files for symbol and reference. (Also with some poor handling of whitespace in input filenames, but I digress.)

`lorder` is ancient. It's been there since AT&T Unix version 7 (1979).

---

As for the suggestion to use the more modern `ld.gold` for speed, *also* consider using LLVM's [`ld.lld`](https://www.mankier.com/1/ld.lld). LLD is easier to use since it does not require a good link order **at all**. And it's [faster still](https://lld.llvm.org/#performance).