# Is it possible to partially link together archive files?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, ld

I was trying to do

```
ld -r -o test.o lib.a
```

It worked but test.o ended up being very small file even though `lib.a` large file.

But if I do

```
ld -r -o test.o obj1.o obj2.o etc
```

It seems to work.  Just link all object files in `lib.a` )

Essentially is there a way to tell `ld` to take all the object files out of `.a` and link them ?

I’m asking because trying speed up build which creates hundreds of executables but always links with same libraries.  Wanted to instead try linking with one big `.o` file to resolve as much reference as possible before hand.  Basically don’t have `ld` repeat same work each time.

Comment: Trying to get object file as the main output.   If I do one with linking all object files I get test.o being a ELF LSB relocatable.  Same thing if I use the .a but test.o file very small.  I want to in next step link test.o with main.o to create executable

Comment: Does the `ld` command you are using have the `-all_load` switch?

Comment: For some background, see my answer: [gcc ld: method to determine link order of static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168951/5382650) It's tedious to try to force a `.a` to pull in all its `.o` subfiles using `ld`. The usual way is to do: `ar xv mylib.a ; ld -r -o test.r *.o; rm -f *.o ; mv test.r test.o`

Comment: Okay will check it out.  Am using gun linker and Cabot find load-all, also have gold linker

Comment: Does the `--whole-archive` option help?

Comment: Yes !  Looks like this is promising

Comment: Unless the library is of closely interlinked routines so that a program using any of the functions actually ends up using most of them, your proposed method will end up with bigger executables than necessary.