# Error message compiling ARM on C: undefined link to «crc32»

Tags: c, linker, cross-platform, zlib

I try to compile for **ARM 32bit** a C project, which contains links to **zlib** & **minizip** static libraries. I work with CLion IDE on Ubuntu 20. I had installed toolchain:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Then I downloaded ARM deb packages, from which I extracted **libz.a** & **libminizip.a**:

```
zlib1g-dev_1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1_armhf.deb
libminizip-dev_1.1-8build1_armhf.deb
```

Then I try to compile, but have:

```
====================[ Build | all | Default-System ]============================
/home/user/external/clion-2023.1.1/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake --build /home/user/Clion/myproject/cmake-build-default-system --target all -j 1
[3/3] Linking C executable updater
FAILED: updater 
: && /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -fsanitize=address  CMakeFiles/updater.dir/main.c.o CMakeFiles/updater.dir/base64.c.o -o updater  /home/user/Clion/myproject/lib/arm/libz.a  /home/user/Clion/myproject/lib/arm/libminizip.a  /home/user/Clion/myproject/lib/arm/libjansson.a && :
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/user/Clion/myproject/lib/arm/libminizip.a(unzip.o): in function «unzReadCurrentFile»:
(.text+0x144e): undefined link to «crc32»
```

Here is **CmakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(updater C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(updater main.c unpack.h)


set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR /home/user/Clion/myproject/zlib-arm/include)
set(ZLIB_LIBRARY /home/user/Clion/myproject/lib/arm/libz.a)
set(MINIZIP_LIBRARY /home/user/Clion/myproject/lib/arm/libminizip.a)
target_include_directories(updater PRIVATE ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(updater PRIVATE ${ZLIB_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(updater PRIVATE ${MINIZIP_LIBRARY})
```

The survey of the libz.a seems OK:

```
nm /home/user/Clion/myproject/lib/arm/libz.a | grep crc32
crc32.o:
00000645 T crc32
0000064d T crc32_combine
00000481 t crc32_combine_
00000651 T crc32_combine64
00000001 t crc32_little
0000063d T crc32_z
         U crc32
         U crc32
```

I suspect that downloaded libraries might be incompatible. But what to replace them with?
Or build them manually - but how?
Any advice?

Comment: Just a guess ... Try reversing the order of the `target_link_libraries` statements. I presume that `MINIZIP_LIBRARY` wants to call things in `ZLIB_LIBRARY` but `ZLIB_LIBRARY` comes _first_ in the [generated] linker command. linkers do one pass through the `.a` arguments, so when it sees the minizip `.a`, it's already to late to pull in stuff from the zlib `.a` file. You may need to adjust the link order of `libjansson.a` as well.

Comment: I did as you said, and you guess is great! It works!

Comment: I recognized the link ordering issue from the output. But, I said "guess" simply because I'm not super familiar with `cmake`, so I wasn't sure if changing the `target_link_libraries` would work. For more on the ordering issue, see my answer: [gcc ld: method to determine link order of static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168951/5382650)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ... libz.a libminizip.a ...
```

is incorrect: since `libminzip.a` requires symbols from `libz.a`, it should be *before* `libz.a` on the link line.

To understand this better, read [this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).