# gcc: Allow object files in two different linked libraries to depend on each other

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Let's say a function `A` in `libA.a` calls a function `B` in `libB.a`, and a separate function `C` in `libB.a` relies on function `D` in `libA.a`. If you try to link them with `gcc main.c libA.a libB.a`, you will get `undefined reference to D`. If you try `gcc main.c libB.a libA.a`, you will get `undefined reference to B`.

Comment: Hmmm.. that should work without problem. This issue should happen in the opposite case. If you compile with `libA.a` before `libB.a` then libA can call any of libB's functions. Are you just calling exactly `gcc libA.a libB.a`? That of course won't work, you are missing a main. But `gcc main.c libA.a libB.a` should work. Also: define "it won't work" because currently it is unclear what you mean. Add error messages and a [mre].

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168951/5382650

Comment: @CraigEstey Isn't that only for ld? I'm using gcc (`gcc -c` then `ld` doesn't work for me).

Comment: No, it works just fine for `gcc` because it invokes `ld` under the hood. You just have to add `-Wl,*` to escape the linker options. See `man gcc` for documentation on `-Wl`

Comment: @CraigEstey Weird... it says that `--start-group` and `--end-group` is an invalid option.

Comment: @CraigEstey `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` worked perfectly! Can you put this in an answer?

Comment: Since `libA` and `libB` cannot be used without each other, then perhaps they shouldn't be two separate libraries.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I don't have control over the library creation (it's QT).